# How to deal with a problem of surjective functions?

Tags: functions

Here is a problem right here: find all the surjective functions $f :\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such as 
for each $x$ and $y \in\Bbb R$: $f(xf(y)+y^2)=f((x+y)^2)-xf(x)$.

I don't understand really well the principle of surjectivity and I was wondering if my solution is right . And if it's wrong, can you please explain to me the mistake? 
Here is my solution:

As $f$ is surjective for each $y\in\Bbb R$ , there exists $x\in\Bbb R$ such as $f(x)=y$ so there exists $y\in\Bbb R$ such as $f(y)=x+2y$. 
Hence $xf(x)=0$ so $x=0$ ( which means that $f(y)=2y$) or $f(x)=0$ 
And the functions $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=2x$ verify the equation so they are the solutions
And thank you for your help

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ for formatting tips.

Comment: The logic seems unclear, or at least the quantifiers are unclear.  As I understand it, you fix $x$ and seek a $y$ such that $f(y)=x+2y$, yes?  But why should that exist?  If, say, $f(z)=2z$ for all $z$  then $f$ is surjective then $f(y)=x+2y$ only has a solution if $x=0$.  Also note:  the function which is identically $0$ is not surjective.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification